# SMT component identification

Tags: identification

I need to find out what surface mount  this is its black with a  Y  on it [image]

Comment: what was the voltage across it when powered? what is the resistance across it when board is off? what does the silk screen in white font legend say?

Comment: one side reads 19v other side reads 0v i was thinking it was a fuse but seen there is a cap beside it soldered to same traces

Comment: what does the silk mark say? like C22 and F20. what is the package? can you open it from the PCB and measure resistance across it?

Comment: What package size is it?

Answer (score 5):

Going by look and reference designator (F20, mirrored in the OP’s image), it seems to be fuse. One of the fuse from Bourns can match it. Further **confirmation can be made by inspecting the resistance** of it. looking at the copper trace width, it looks like power plane.  See the image below:

[image]

Datasheet:
http://www.bourns.com/docs/Product-Datasheets/sf0603f.pdf

Comment: Why would you put a fuse in parallel with a capacitor?

Comment: @winny not 100% sure whether it is Fuse and the component next to it is a capacitor too.. only OP have to confirm at least the resistance of component of interest. Even, resistors come now without marking.

Comment: I find a resitor far far more plauisble than a resistor due to said capacitor and the resonable asumption that this is not the "start"/input of the circuit, more and RC in the middle of the schematic.

Comment: @winny if it was indeed a resistor it could be for some fuse blown indication through a LED down the line.